# Cordova own plugin gives error: Object has no method 'apply' on cordova.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've made my own cordova plugin, but I can't get it works.
This is the java file. myTest.java

```
package com.testplugin.test;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class myTest extends CordovaPlugin { 
@Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("giveHello")) {
            String results = "Hello world";
            callbackContext.success(results);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My plugin javascript file, mytest.js

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

module.exports = {
     showhello: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
           exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "myTest", "giveHello", [null]);
     }
}
```

This is the plugin.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-mytest" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<name>Test plugin</name>
<js-module name="myTest" src="www/mytest.js">
    <clobbers target="myTest" />
</js-module>
<platform name="android">
    <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
        <feature name="myTest">
            <param name="android-package" value="com.testplugin.test.myTest" />
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/android/test/myTest.java" target-dir="src/com/testplugin/test" />
</platform>
```

But when I call it in www folder, in myapp.js

```
myTest.showhello('myTest', success, error);
```

I got this error:

> Error in Success callbackId: myTest1490933768 : TypeError: Object myTest has no method 'apply'", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (312)

Would someone show me what mistake I've made? What does the error mean?

Answer (score 0):

Writing js and java file is not enough. You need to create Plugin.xml and bind js method with the java plugin file created. For eg.

```
<js-module src="www/android/proximity-notification.js" name="ProximityNotification">
        <clobbers target="ProximityNotification" />
    </js-module>
```

For complete reference see https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I have that plugin.xml, I didn't put it because i think it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I've found my fault.
It's in mytest.js

Instead of `showhello: function(successCallback, errorCallback)`, I have to do something like `showhello: function(message, successCallback, errorCallback)`